# wp-load.php disabling the ob_flush to work correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

this works, e.g. the output comes one after another:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
  echo 'printing...<br>';
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
die("bb");
```

this does not work:

```
require_once(  __DIR__ .'/../../../wp-load.php' );
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
    {
      echo 'printing...<br>';
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(1);
    }
    die("bb");
```

e.g. the script halts, and waits until all data is done.

it is a multi site install, and local install.

**EDIT**

the response headers where output flushing worked:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 20 Jun 2016 01:33:33 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.22-1+donate.sury.org~trusty+1
```

her are my response headers FROM THE FAILED ATTEMPT:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 20 Jun 2016 01:27:36 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.22-1+donate.sury.org~trusty+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked for me (after applying all the disable gzip and disable compression tutorials):

note the:
`ob_end_flush();`

```
require(__DIR__ ."/../../wp-load.php");


ob_end_flush();


//header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); //this was not required in my case
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
  echo 'printing...<br>';
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
die("bb2");
```

Comment: does seem a bit strange needing to do this for a core load, maybe worth looking for an `ob_start` somewhere in the theme or plugin that is not closed? might be hard to find though.

Comment: I had this problem for months... 
but this simple, unexpected `ob_end_flush();` at the beginning fixed it!
thanks @toskan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the configuration of your WP installation, but it might happen due to buffering that is done by the application (php) or by your server (apache?).

Some configuration can cause the output to be compressed (gzipped, mostly) before being sent back to the user, therfore your application must finish with all of the the output before it can be compressed.

You can check (using the Developer Tools) if the output was compressed in each of the requests (you should check for the `Content-Encoding` header).

Comment: i mean the php code in wp-load.php MUST trigger some buffering / something. Otherwise, there is some serious magic going on. I just don't know what and how to revert it

Comment: You have 2 different runs, update your 2 responses (unless they are the same. If so - write it).

Comment: just letting you know that i seemed to have found a solution. I found it by pure luck i guess, this was wild trying out.